# webgrid paging click makes grid state goes wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

[screen shot shows webgrid state after paging number clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMozV.jpg)

Paging working, grid add/update/delete working as expected. Ajaxcontainer working fine which replaces only grid on page click not entire page replaced with only webgrid. Only thing is grid mode is collapsed? where i am missing.

Partial View

```html
<div id="gridposition" style="overflow: scroll; height: 300px; overflow-x: hidden;">
    <a href="javascript://" id="btnAddNew">Add New(+)</a>

    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, defaultSort: "QuestionID", rowsPerPage: 3, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridposition");
    }

    <div id="gridContent" style="padding-right: 30%;">
        @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "result" },  
         tableStyle: "wGrid",
         fillEmptyRows: false,
         alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
         headerStyle: "gridHeader",
         mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
         firstText: "<< First",
         previousText: " < Previous",
         nextText: "Next >",
         lastText: "Last >>",
        emptyRowCellValue: null,
    columns:
        grid.Columns( ....
```

Partial view contains script for grid button click events and also this line

```js
 $('.edit-mode').hide();
```

Main View

```js
var url = '@Url.Action("Filter","AddSurveyQuestions")';
        $.get(url, { campaignid: campaignid, languagename: languagename }, function (result) {

            $('#SurveyViewGrid').html(result);
        }); ....
```

Main View calling partial view

```js
<div id="SurveyViewGrid">
                @Html.Partial("SurveyView", Model.SurveyQuestions)
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

modified partial view (moving getHTML outside the parent div) removes the problem i specified.

```js
<div id="gridposition" style="overflow: scroll; height: 300px; overflow-x: hidden;">
    <a href="javascript://" id="btnAddNew">Add New(+)</a>

    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, defaultSort: "QuestionID", rowsPerPage: 3, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridposition");
    }
    </div>

    <div id="gridContent" style="padding-right: 30%;">
        @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "result" },  
         tableStyle: "wGrid",
         fillEmptyRows: false,
         alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
         headerStyle: "gridHeader",
         mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
         firstText: "<< First",
         previousText: " < Previous",
         nextText: "Next >",
         lastText: "Last >>",
        emptyRowCellValue: null,
    columns:
        grid.Columns( ....
```